# Responsive table (pure html/css)

Tags: html, css

`Code`: https://jsfiddle.net/qo44rgop/

I want the table to move the td's to the next line if the screen becomes to small (now it extends the table beyond the width of the div). I tried to use `margin: auto` on the table, it centered it on the div but it didn't adapt to the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

One thing you might want to consider is changing the display property of  to 'block' under certain size restrictions. Example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
  td{
    display:block
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use [@media](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) and set the width of the table cells to 100% (or change the `display` property) when the screen width fits with your concept of small (I think 768px was the normal `max-width` for mobile devices, don't remember now).

You have an example in the link I gave, at the bottom.